# a better understanding of this structure

Tags: grammar, articles, uncountable-nouns

> Parents have a better **understanding** for\of their children than
>   schools.
>
> Fathers and mothers have a better **knowledge** about their children than
>   schools.

Why “a” is used here although “understanding” and ”knowledge” are uncountable? especially that we don't say

> Education creates **a** better children.

Answer (score 1):

1. [*The Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/understanding) says that "an understanding" can be a countable or singular noun, so

> Parents have a better understanding <s>for</s> of their children than schools.

is perfectly fine.

2. [*The Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/knowledge?q=knowledge+) says that "knowledge" can be a singular or uncountable noun, so

> Fathers and mothers have a better knowledge about their children than schools (do).

or

> Fathers and mothers have better knowledge about their children than schools (do).

are both fine.

Comment: Thank you. This changes everything. However, Understanding can be singular when it means "Sympathy", but it is uncountable when it means "knowledge".
I assume that native English speakers always mean Sympathy when they feel that the construction is like "a better understanding", so they feel that it is wrong when I say "better understanding" without a.

In other words, do you ever say "better understanding" without "a"?

Comment: Maybe:     “Alice has reached **a** better understanding of Advanced algebra.   Since her last report card, Carol has reached better understanding of Math, Physics and French, but needs improvement in Spanish.”